# Javascript Need a basic syntax explaination

Tags: javascript

```js
var x = 5;

function test2(x) {
  x = 7;
}

test2(8);
alert(x);
```

Why exactly is this putting out the global var x=5, without being affected by anything within the function.

Comment: The `x` parameter in the function is [shadowing](https://medium.com/@mayuminishimoto/understanding-variable-shadowing-with-javascript-58fc108c8f03) the variable from the outer scope.

Comment: Try changing `test2(x)` to `test2(a)`.

Comment: @Justinas that's not the correct dupe target. We have one for specifically this scenario when a parameter shadows a variable somewhere. It's nothing to do with references.

Answer (score 0):

Because you passed a param called x, which is the same name as your global var. Try this out:

```js
var x = 5;

function test2(y) {
  x = y;
}

test2(8);
alert(x);
```